# LocalStorage not able to add class 'open' and keep it

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am using LocalStorage to keep a toggle banner open / closed. 
Unfortunately I have been unable to correctly implement keeping an open class on the toggle #button of the banner to change the style of it accordingly.

my code:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().slideToggle(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('display', $('#banner').is(':hidden'));
    });
});
var block = localStorage.getItem('display');
if (block == 'true') {
    $('#banner').hide()
}
```

my html

```
<div id="banner_container">
    <div id="banner">
        <img src="#">
    </div>
    <button id="button" href="javascript:void(0);"></button> <!-- toggle 'open' class if banner is visible / hidden and keep it in LocalStorage -->
</div>
```

I tried setting the toggleClass ( `$(this).toggleClass('open');` ) to the slideToggle function but this doesn't seem to be the correct approach as it is not correlated with the LocalStorage behaviour. Any advice?

Comment: Don't you want to know whether `$('#banner').is(':hidden')` instead of `$(this).is(':hidden')` which is referencing your button (which I assume is always visible as its your toggle)?

Comment: Correct. updated the post

Comment: localStorage defaults to strings unless parsed via JSON.parse. That being said, this could be an equals operator issue. @user3615851 did you try using ===?

Comment: Hi, I experimented but didn't have an effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by toggling the 'activeClass' or 'open' and checking if it exists on document load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().slideToggle(function() {
      localStorage.setItem('display', $('#banner').is(':hidden'));
    });
  });
  var block = localStorage.getItem('display');
  if (block == 'true') {
    $('#banner').hide()
  }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    $('#button').toggleClass('activeClass');
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (!$('#banner').is(':hidden')) {
    $('#button').addClass('activeClass');
  } else if (!$('#banner').is(':visible')) {
    $('#button').removeClass('activeClass');
  }
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fcewjh7a/17/

Answer (score 0):

wrap your javascript in a jquery document ready call. Your problem is that the javascript to hide the banner is executing before the DOM renders the banner element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function () {
      $(this).siblings().slideToggle(function() {
      localStorage.setItem('display', $('#banner').is(':hidden'));
      });
  });
  var block = localStorage.getItem('display');
  if (block == 'true') {
      $('#banner').hide()
  }
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fcewjh7a/3/

Comment: Hi, I think haven't presented myself clear. You can see my issue presented here: https://jsfiddle.net/fcewjh7a/6/ . When the banner is closed the button turns black. After I refresh then button is not black anymore.

Comment: I've created a jsFiddle to illustrate the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/fcewjh7a/10/

After refresh the class 'ActiveClass' should be kept on the button but it is not.